# S3 storage not blocking access to my private folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3

I have 3 S3 folders: `media`, `static` and `backup`. My policy explicitly states to  only allow access to my `media` and `static` folders:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1597134400227",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stm15023423426864",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::****-bucket/media/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stm23423443439230",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::****-bucket/static/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

however, when I copy the file path of a file in my private `backup` folder into another browser (where I'm not logged in), it downloads the file...

How is this happening? Not only this but the `backup` folder also has PUT access even though I haven't granted that - I've just tested performing a backup via my python/django backend and it successfully backs up my database to the `backup` folder.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: *"when I copy the file path of a file...into another browser"*  Copy from where? The S3 console?  Does this URL that you're copying have anything in it after the path, such as a query string beginning with `?` and then a lot of parameters that begin with `X-Amz-`?

Comment: Check the bucket is publically accessible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible explanations are:

- You are copying a Pre-Signed URL from the Amazon S3 management console, which includes additional information that permits access, even to private objects
- The individual object has public permissions on them
- You have granted permissions (eg Put) on the bucket itself